# Sequence for express app route

Tags: node.js, express

For below code logic. I found that "checkLogin", "checkAuthorization" was called before user.load. Is there anyone can teach me how can to change code so that users.load will called firstly?

```
app.param('userId', users.load);
app.get('/users/:userId', checkLogin, checkAuthorization, users.show)
```

Answer (score 0):

As `app.param` maps logic to route parameters (see http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param) you seem to be missing a colon in `/users/:userId`.

If, however, the route `/users/userId` is correct and you do not want a parameter there, then you should not be using `app.param`. Instead you can register a generic middleware function to handle whatever you want *before* it comes to handling  `get`by doing (do this *before* defining `app.get`):

```
app.use(function(request, response, next){
    // do stuff
    next();
});
```

Comment: sorry, i missed colon in original post. I do want a parameter there as `userId`, and expect the parameter handler be called firstly, before calling `get` middleware. I suppose `app.param` handler will be called before `app.get` middleware.